# creating a callinst to an external function

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm making an instrumentation pass. The pass is supposed to modify the given IR in a specefic way. One of the required modifications is to insert a call to a function at a specific location. 
This is the signature of the called function:

```
void myclass::foo(Function *f, BasicBlock* b)
```

This function's prototype is in an `foofile.h` file in *include/llvm*
And the function definition is in `foofile.cpp` file in the *MCJIT* folder.
and running `make` at this folder works fine and the `foofile.cpp` is compiled with `MCJIT.cpp` and another function in the same file works just fine as expected.
Not back to the instrumentation pass. How can I insert a callinst to the foo function in the given IR?
Here is the snippet that inserts the call:

```
Type* retTy = Type::getInt32Ty(C);
FunctionType* FuncTy = FunctionType::get(retTy, false);
PointerType* PtrToFuncTy = PointerType::get(FuncTy, 0);
Constant *fun = M->getOrInsertFunction("foo", Type::getVoidTy(C), PtrToFuncTy, Type::getLabelTy(C), nullptr);
Function *dofoo = cast<Function>(fun);
Instruction* dofooCall = CallInst::Create(fun, Args2, "", bb);
```

**Note:** `Args2` is an arraylist containing 2 value pointers to a function and a basicblock, `bb` is the basicblock to insert the call in.

When I run the pass using op on a given IR, it produces a declaration and a call correctly like this:

**declaration:**

```
declare void @foo(i32 ()*, label)
```

**call:**

```
call void @foo(i32 ()* @main, label %for.cond)
```

But when I try to run the resulting .ll file using lli, everything explodes! This the first 2 lines before the stacktrace:

```
Can't get register for value!
UNREACHABLE executed at /home/marwayusuf/llvm-env/llvm/lib/CodeGen/SelectionDAG/SelectionDAGBuilder.cpp:1158!
```

I concluded that the problem is it can't find the foo function. If this is the problem, how can I create the callinst correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If the function is a member of the class myclass it's going to have a this-pointer as the first argument. C++ method names also have name mangling so it's not using the symbol "foo". When using mcjit it lowers your IR to machine code, it doesn't actually execute the IR so when running you're not passing llvm::Function or llvm::BasicBlock so the instrumentation function won't work even if you called it like that.

Comment: Thanks for you help. But, as far as I know, when calling any function, the jit looks for this function to see if it's already compiled before or not. That means that the function object remains alive, and that's what I need. Besides, what if I want to call "foo" function without any parameters? How I can find the mangled name?